# Temporary creation of nodes and relationships?

Tags: neo4j, cascading-deletes

Is there a way to create nodes and relationships and at some point delete them all without affecting the rest of the database.

What I have in mind is if there is some hidden attribute of nodes/relationships let say create time , so I can delete everything from some point in time until now.

A transaction commit/rollback wont work , because it is usable for short periods of time.

Answer (score 3):

If your use case is suitable (e.g., you are just using the neo4j browser to *visualize* some "temporary" data together with stored data), you may be able to use the APOC plugin's [virtual nodes/relationships](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#virtual) support. Such "virtual" nodes/relationships are not actually stored in the DB, so there is nothing to delete afterwards.